# BSP Application upload generates hashed filenames without folder structure

Tags: sapui5, sap-bsp

After the upload the a **sapui5** application on the SAP system has a strange structure. The files are not in the same structure as they were on my machine and the filenames are hashed, except MIMEs. So I am not able to find e.g. a specific "**controller.js**". The application is still fully working.

In this specific case the SAP Program `"/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD"` was used to upload the application. The upload protocol looks fine, no hint about renaming or similar. So I am not sure if the problem is with the system or the program.

All the hash files name should be normal naming and should be in sub-folders components. Even the "**index.html**" file has a hash, this cases a problem when click on `"test application"`, because it opens the hash in the URL. The hash, which is the path and the filename cannot be opened, but if I replace the hash with the original path -> it works

http://scn.sap.com/thread/3809662

Answer (score 0):

A work colleague found the issue in the sap system. It seems it is not allowed to have path + filename longer than 70 characters. If it is longer it hashes the path and filename to place it under the project root folder.

The german comment seems very strange, though ... "Name length should not be a 
problem. Do we have anyhow a max length?"

It also creates a file containing the mapping from filepath + filename to hash.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not use file names longer than 70 characters.
Also you should not use '**-**' in your file names.

As far as I know the only allowed characters for valid BSP paths are:
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789./_"